# Using gcc __uint128_t and later scanf of uint8_t lead to UB

Tags: c++

I've been playing around with __uint128_t in gcc and came across the fact that such code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    __uint128_t very_long = 1;
    std::uint8_t num;
    scanf("%u", &num);
    printf("%llu", static_cast<uint64_t>(very_long));
    return 0;
}
```

leads to different behaviour depending on the level of optimization.
If compiled with **-O0** it prints **0**, whereas compiled with **-O1**, **-O2** or **-O3** it prints **1** as expected.

However if I enforce alignment, the result is **1** regardless of the optimization level.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    __uint128_t very_long = 1;
    std::uint8_t num __attribute__ ((aligned(4)));
    scanf("%u", &num);
    printf("%llu", static_cast<uint64_t>(very_long));
    return 0;
}
```

So the question is - is it some kind of a bug or am I missing something?

P.S. Used godbolt.org to compile, tried both x86-64 gcc 10.2 and x86-64 gcc 12.2 (--std=c++17 -OX)

Comment: Undefined behavior. `scanf` is a type-unsafe C library function. `%u` expects an pointer to an `unsigned`, instead of a pointer to `std::uint8_t`, which is going to be an `unsigned char`. Hillarity ensues.

Comment: you should also enable more warning, `-Wall` is enough to warn you at this case https://godbolt.org/z/oGsWPdzKq

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you have a sick sense of humor.